# Reboot Chrome OS running in VMWare

Tags: google-chrome-os

Downloaded the Chrome OS VmWare image today and was taking it for a test drive.  I don't know how to shutdown or issue a reboot for this OS.  Anyway to drop to a terminal window in Chrome OS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> will present you with a Terminal, you can then use the `reboot` command.

Comment: Which does Ctrl+At+T do? Shutdown/reboot, or open a terminal window? :)  (If it opens a terminal window, any idea how he would then reboot?)

Comment: Ultimately the only question in his post is "Anyway to drop to a terminal window in Chrome OS?" as it is preceeded by a question mark. The reboot command will reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-Alt-t to bring up the terminal window.
Then "sudo shutdown -h now"
Hopefully, you chose to configure the shared password when you built the OS, or were provided it by the VMWare image builder.

Comment: shutdown -h now will shut down the system, not reboot it.

Comment: in Linux-land, shutdown -r now will reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Alt+F2 drops to the console.  Ctrl+Alt+F1 will take you back to the GUI.  If you can't log in, use Ctrl+Alt+F2 to get a console; otherwise, Ctrl+Alt+T is the preferred method - use Alt+Tab to switch back and forth.

The Ctrl+Alt+F2 trick can also be used in most flavors of Linux to bring up a (different) console, though X (the Linux GUI) is usually Ctrl+Alt+F7 rather than Ctrl+Alt+F1.

Of course, you can also use the VMWare power down (or reboot) command in the VMWare menu outside of the OS itself, especially since it seems the "official" shutdown mechanism for Chrome OS running natively is the power button.